# POSTFIX+OPENDKIM : How to reject untrusted domains without keeping mails in queue?

Tags: email, postfix

We have creates an smtp server for our webapps.

This server runs Under Ubuntu with Postfix and Opendkim.
We have 40 domains with 40 DKIM keys. My config is the same as described in [this blog post](http://blog.tjitjing.com/index.php/2012/03/guide-to-install-opendkim-for-multiple-domains-with-postfix-and-debian.html.)

It works just fine.

My problem : If developers create an email with a domain my server doesn't know in the trusted list, it will send it, and block the mail in between 2 and 3 minutes.

Can I do something to make postfix reject untrusted mails immediately?

I've tried in `opendkim` conf `ADSPNoSuchDomain=true` and `ADSPAction=reject`. My mails are rejected, but still waiting in the queue for 2-3 minutes.

I've found nothing usable in Postfix to block these domains.

Answer (score 2):

I've found how to reject untrusted domains from my local network :

1) In `/etc/postfix/main.cf` add the line :

```
smtpd_sender_restrictions = check_sender_access hash:/etc/postfix/sender_access, reject
```

2) In `/etc/postfix` create the file `sender_access` and copy/paste all permitted domains.

3) Execute the command `postmap sender_access` to create a `sender_access.db` file.

4) Restart Postfix.

Now if I want to send a mail from my local network with a domain that doesn't exist in the `sender_access.db` file, Postfix rejects the mail immediately.